# Convert Date to UnixTimeStamp in MySQL gives error LIMIT 0, 25

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp

I have Dates Table in which one of the field name is START_DATE (DATE) type

My Query is:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(SELECT START_DATE FROM `mobile_registrations_dates` WHERE SNO=1)
```

I used SNO=1 because I want to fetch only one UnixTimeStamp value but the above query gives error as follows

```
**Error**
SQL query: ￼ 

SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(SELECT START_DATE FROM `mobile_registrations_dates` WHERE LIMIT 1) LIMIT 0, 25

MySQL said: ￼ 
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to 
use near 'SELECT START_DATE FROM `mobile_registrations_dates` WHERE LIMIT 1) 
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

Comment: `SELECT START_DATE FROM mobile_registrations_dates  LIMIT 1`  remove where

Comment: Just remove the `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of nested query I have used this query-

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(START_DATE) FROM `mobile_registrations_dates` WHERE SNO = 1
```